# How can I link dynamic library depending on another dynamic library?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, ld

I make a program using a dynamic library, libexample.so. The dynamic library depends on another dynamic library, libtool.so.

It looks linker succeeded linking the libexample.so because of message from gcc.

```
Building target: libexample.so
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -L/home/takehiro/Documents/documents/code/lib/tool -shared -o "libexample.so"  ./classes/example.o ./classes/example_template.o ./classes/example_test.o ./classes/impl.o   -ltool
Finished building target: libexample.so

cp libexample.so /home/takehiro/Documents/documents/code/lib/example
```

However, it failed to link it with the libtool.so.

```
ldd /home/takehiro/Documents/documents/code/lib/example/libexample.so 
    ...
    libtool.so => not found
    ...
```

I checked existence of the libtool.so under /home/takehiro/Documents/documents/code/lib/tool which is pointed by -L optoin at above linker by

```
ls /home/takehiro/Documents/documents/code/lib/tool

libtool.so
```

This is the first time to use a dynamic library depending another dynamic library. So I am so confused. Is it normal or malfunction? Why it cannot link them?
 Does someone have a suggestion or a solution to me? I am very glad it.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All that the `-L` option does is tell the linker where the shared library is, at link time.

This does not have any effect on where the runtime loader searches for shared libraries. That's why the shared library fails to be loaded at runtime.

You also need to pass the `-rpath` option to the linker, when you're linking your shared library, in order to set the `RPATH` attribute on the shared library, that specifies where its dependencies are to be searched for. Something like

```
g++ -L/home/takehiro/Documents/documents/code/lib/tool \
    -Wl,-rpath=/home/takehiro/Documents/documents/code/lib/tool \
    ... remaining options
```

Comment: Thank you Sam Varshavchik for answering it. Please let me confirm following. In case of execution file, I can use LD_LIBRARY_PATH to let it know the location of library. However in case of shared library depending on  another shared library, it does not use LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Is it right?

Comment: It does, but using `-rpath` makes it possible not to use LD_LIBRARY_PATH explicitly.

Comment: Thank you again, Sam Varshavchik. I used LD_LIBRARY_PATH through eclipse. It is a temporal LD_LIBRAY_PATH. It might be a reason the execution program could not find reference of function in the shared library. Anyway I will use -rpath. Thank you very much.